# how to fix java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

```
public class VitalCompare implements Comparator<VitalReportsDetails> {
    @Override
    public int compare(VitalReportsDetails vitalReportsDetails, VitalReportsDetails t1) {
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt((vitalReportsDetails.getValue().equals("") ? "0" : vitalReportsDetails.getValue()));

        int n2 = Integer.parseInt((t1.getValue().equals("")? "0" : t1.getValue()));
        if (n1 >= n2) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;

    }

}
```

calling like this :

```
int min=Integer.parseInt(Collections.min(listOfData, new VitalCompare()).getValue());
```

**Logcat**

```
  8-07 11:17:49.604 27972-27972/com.cognistrength.caregiver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.cognistrength.caregiver, PID: 27972
                                                                             java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                                 at com.cognistrength.caregiver.adapters.VitalGraphAdapter.onBindViewHolder(VitalGraphAdapter.java:123)
                                                                                 at com.cognistrength.caregiver.adapters.VitalGraphAdapter
```

Comment: Just throwing this out there... why is `vitalReportsDetails.getValue()` a `String` and not an `Integer`?

Comment: The comparator is used to sort the data, it does not change them..

Comment: Also, your `Comparator` needs to return `0` when the two values are the same.  Yours does not.

Comment: how to fix .. this .

Comment: Start by making `getValue()` return an `int` and not a `String`.  Then your fix becomes trivial.

Comment: means i dint get ur answer @JoeC

Comment: as @IntelliJ Amiya said, it has no value that can be convert to int. for example if the value is "Ali", how can you expect to change that to integer!?

Comment: Post the full exception, the text of the exception for me (Oracle java 8) is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "", if it is really saying Invalid int: "" then you have a different error than I have seen or a different version of the JVM.  You are handling the single invalid string empty string, any non-numeric string will produce the same error, 'Ali' for example as Mehran suggested.  If the string has nothing but unprintable characters then the exception message could show an empty string.

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/zsmL2GMfbaUt3HwmR73nYy

Answer (score 3):

You get "" because that value is the min value in that list (your comparator said that). You can handle that by simply call 
`String temp = Collections.min(listOfData, new VitalCompare()).getValue();
int min = Integer.parseInt(temp.equals("") ? "0" : temp);`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use:

```
vitalReportsDetails.getValue().equals("") || vitalReportsDetails.isEmpty() ? "0" : vitalReportsDetails.getValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

**[NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)**

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a
>   string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have
>   the appropriate format.

```
     int n1 = Integer.parseInt((vitalReportsDetails.getValue().equals("") ? "0" : vitalReportsDetails.getValue()));
     int n2 = Integer.parseInt((t1.getValue().equals("")? "0" : t1.getValue()));
```

Problem coming from **`n1 & n2`** . **Debug** both .

The statement **`[Either n1 or n2]`**  would throw **NumberFormatException** because it generate **`String`** Which cannot be parsed to **`int`**.

Comment: I am converting String  to Integer

Comment: @Adevelopment for test case DEBUG please

Comment: @Adevelopment You are Getting `SPACE`

Comment: i have applied isEmpty and trim also then also same exception is coming

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened to me , this happens when string is in the form of **Float** or **Double** or like other form other than numbers this error throws if it is in form of double or float try like below method

```
    float floatstring = FLoat.parseFloat("your_string");
    //then
    int int1= (int) Math.round(floatstring );
```

for **Double**

```
double doublestring = Double.parseDouble("100.22");
        //then
        int int2= (int) Math.round(doublestring );
```

Comment: i am getting String that we have to COnvert in int

Comment: Yes , First convert your string to float or double and then convert it to int . See the above code .

Comment: I have edited the answer recheck now

Comment: still same issue i have changed according ur logic

Comment: @ Omar Danisha   are u there can u check my code ?

Comment: ok ,  actually it should work , how is your string received ? , if the string is in like "hello" it can't parse ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151240/discussion-between-adevelopment-and-omar-danisha).